# 478 MHz band, allowed for hobbyist use in USA?

Tags: spectrum

Somebody [advised me](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=18439021&postcount=15363) to look at this [wireless module](http://www.goodluckbuy.com/apc220-wireless-communication-module-for-arduinousb-converter.html) as a lower-cost alternative to xbee.

I noticed that it operates on the 478 MHz band.  Is this band permitted for hobbyist use in the United States?

[image]

Comment: It operates on other bands as well. Read your datasheets, and don't trust marketing blurbs on distributor websites!

Comment: Also, to the close-voters: RF communication is central to our scope.  While this is just one module, and just one frequency, it's OK to be somewhat localized in stuff that's this on-topic.  I'd suggest that we keep this question open, but please bring any discussion to Meta (or, at the very least, post a comment or flag) if you want to debate this point.  Otherwise, you can just let the close votes expire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the chart [here](http://www.ntia.doc.gov/osmhome/spectrumreform/Spectrum%20Use%20Summary%20Master-06%2021%2010.pdf), 478 MHz falls into a band that is allocated to Fixed Land Mobile Broadcasting.  The description says, "The federal agencies use this band for land mobile radio communication systems for shared systems and mutual aid responses with public safety agencies (fire fighting, law enforcement, medical, etc.) in local communities."  According to the footnotes (which can be found [here](http://www.ntia.doc.gov/osmhome/alloctbl/foot_ng.html)), none of these applications includes unlicensed use.

478 MHz is not an allocated amateur band, so even if you had a ham license you could not transmit on that frequency.

The Wikipedia page on [industrial, scientific and medical (ISM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band) usage also lists the frequency bands that are allocated for unlicensed use.  478 MHz is not on that list.

Based on this evidence it is illegal for you to use a transmitter on 478 MHz in the United States.

Answer (score 7):

### **Executive Summary / tl;dr**

No, 478 MHz is not allowed for hobbyist use in the USA, but this can be configured to operate at other legal frequencies like 433 MHz.

## **Frequency ranges of the module**

According to the [manual for the APC220](http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/TEL0005/APC220%20manual%202.pdf), it has a working frequency of 431 MHz to 478 MHz, which includes the 433 MHz ISM band, which is usable by hobbyists.  The [datasheet](http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/TEL0005/APC220%20manual%202.pdf), hosted on the website of the distributor who wrote the manual in the first link, claims  418MHz to 455MHz performance, but shows a screenshot of the PC configuration software where the user is setting the frequency to 485 MHz (Perhaps that's for the ACP230, based on the title bar?).

In the end, if you're extremely worried about regulatory compliance and really want to use this device, I'd suggest trying to find out what the RF IC is.  That part should have better documentation and better information on EMC testing and legal operation.  The most authoritative source for this module that I could find is [this datasheet in Chinese](http://www.appcon.com.cn/video/upload/2009061934559124.pdf) on the manufacturer's website (the [home page](http://appconn.com/) of which is incredibly spartan).

## **Sugggestion**

If you're willing to play around with this for a while to save a few bucks, then go for it.  No one is likely to show up at your door with a spectrum analyzer before you can figure out how to configure it for 433MHz operation.  However, *especially* since you're a hobbyist, I'd suggest you stay at work for an extra hour or two.  Spend the time that you would have been tearing your hair out debugging this thing and digging through Engrish datasheets, make a few bucks, and buy a well-documented, popular, easy to use, guaranteed legal tool.  **When you're working at low quantities, time is money.**

Comment: Your suggestion is good and is what I will do, even without regard to the frequency issue... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the FCC web site, 478 MHz is allocated to the Offshore Radiotelephone Service. Using those modules would be illegal in the USA.